# Now 'render preview' wont show falling particle w/o cf12

Tags: rendering, particles

I posted an earlier question about a particle system not showing up based on the first minute of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wv23dh6d3oE.

The particles fall from the plane in the above but for me the particles don't fall on the render preview (press <kbd>Z</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>).

I made the particle parents appear *Render > Render As* to *halo* as this

[image: 1]

[image].

I also set *Unborn* on under *Extra*.
Why do I have do I have to do full render to see the particles fall ?

Answer (score 1):

What YouTuber 'Rendered in Blender' DOES NOT SAY is that he pre-rendered the snow. I know because I watched the blender 'timeliness the bottom of the blender window, you  will see the blue rectangle with the frame # in white. The blue rectangle was moving and # increasing but the author edited that out to get it under a minute.  FLIMFLAMMER HIM.

Comment: To be fair, no one wants to watch a loading bar